# How do I delete an email from outlook in such a way that it does not qualify for restoration via the "recover deleted items" functionality?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

How do I delete an email from outlook in such a way that it does not qualify for restoration via the "recover deleted items" functionality?

There are situations where I need to delete critical information that is sent to me from outside our network. I have to adhere to certain security policies that say that certain information must be deleted if it is sent to me.

I am concerned that this restoration capability is preventing me from truly getting rid of the data immediately.

I am using Outlook 2010 and 2013.

The email is housed in Office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a server-side function that's not in the user's control.  Discuss changing the retention settings/policies with your Exchange/Office 365 admin.

[Here's some related info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364752(v=exchg.150).aspx) and info on how to set it up (in Exchange 2010):

Comment: We still need to retain most emails, but when sensitive information needs to be purged, do you know if this can be performed on a case by case basis?

Comment: It can be set differently for specific mailboxes if needed, but not on an email-by-email basis. Again, the Outlook user has no control over if it hits that folder or not, it's up to the Exchange administrator to set the setting.

Comment: Report the event, get the proper people involve, this is an administrator task